# How to make swipe back in left side in single view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I made more than one view without taking new Controller class , I used `UIgestureRecognizer` but it not look better.

I want to swipe same like ios device, when we start to swipe from left side corner.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with scrollview.

Steps:

1)First place a scrollview that fills the full screen.

2)Next create a container view which is as big as to hold your two views.

```
    let containerSize = CGSize(width: 640.0, height: 640.0)
    containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),size:containerSize))
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
```

3) Now you create your view 1 , view2 and add them to container view.

4) Set the scrollview content size to container size

```
scrollView.contentSize = containerSize;
```

5) Then set the scrollview delegate method

```
    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView!) -> UIView!{
      return containerView 
}
```